# SQL*PLUS Concatenation Issues

Tags: sql, oracle

This is for SQL*PLUS

I have a table "Patient" which has 5 fields.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(PAT_ID         CHAR (4) PRIMARY KEY,
 PAT_NAME       VARCHAR (7),
 ADMITTED       DATE,
 ROOM           CHAR (3),
 DOCTOR         VARCHAR (7));

INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES
(1001, 'FRED', '30-MAR-07', 101, 'PAYNE');
```

I want to create a view where my output to look like this:

```
Patient      Doctor       Room         Admitted    
"-----------------------------------------------"
1001 Fred    Payne        101      March 31, 2007
```

The problem is that I want to concatenate Pat_name and Pat_ID into their own separate "Patient" column but **ALSO** have the other three fields also concatenated with it(notice there is no separation in the 'dashes').

Basically, I have 5 fields.  For simplicity's sake, let's call them fields "1, 2, 3, 4, 5".

I want to combine ALL of them together, but FIRST, I need to combine fields 1 and 2.  This small column (fields 1 and 2 combined) will be called "Patient".  THEN, I need to concatenate fields 3, 4, and 5 WITH my Patient column so that all 5 fields are now concatenated together but with only 4 headings.

Comment: I'd struggle to come up with a more innapropriate design for a table than this one. Leaving aside the very odd naming convention, I see at least 7 faults in the table structure.

Comment: Take a look at sqlplus formatting options: [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081534](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081534). You can set headings off, set a title the way you want, do column formats, etc.

Comment: Do your school's instructions say "get the good folks on StackOverflow to do your assignment for you"?  Thought not.  Your other thread provided sufficient information for you to have figured this out on your own own.  Instead you post a duplicate question.  V poor.

Comment: @symcbean - turns out it's a school project.  If this is what kids are getting taught these days no wonder there's so much shonky code out in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the expressions together with the Oracle `||` concatenation operator.

To get the spacing, you can use the RPAD function to pad out the expressions to a specified length (or truncate them to the specified length if they are longer).

```
COL myline HEADING "Patient      Doctor       Room         Admitted"

SELECT RPAD(p.PAT_ID,5)||RPAD(p.PAT_NAME,8)||RPAD(p.DOCTOR,13)
       ||RPAD(p.ROOM,4)||TO_CHAR(p.ADMITTED,'Month dd, yyyy')
       AS myline
  FROM patient p
 ORDER BY p.PAT_ID
```

The date value you show on your line would actually be formatted as

```
March     31, 2007
```

(with extra space in the month name, Oracle reserves space for the longest month name 'September' (?) in that format model.

---

You may also need to add a SQL*Plus directive to specify the length reserved for display of the column, e.g.:

```
COL myline FORMAT A48
```

---

If you could work with something that looks like this:

```
Patient      Doctor       Room   Admitted    
------------ ------------ ------ ------------------
1001 Fred    Payne        101    March     31, 2007
```

Then something like this:

```
COL Patient  FORMAT A13
COL Doctor   FORMAT A13
COL Room     FORMAT A6
COL Admitted FORMAT A21

set lines 41
set feedback off

SELECT RPAD(p.PAT_ID,5)||RPAD(p.PAT_NAME,8) AS "Patient"
     , RPAD(p.DOCTOR,13) AS "Doctor"
     , RPAD(p.ROOM,6) AS "Room"
     , TO_CHAR(p.ADMITTED,'Month dd, yyyy') AS "Admitted"
  FROM patient p
 ORDER BY p.PAT_ID
```